# Error when start server after install @angular/flex-layout package problem

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-flex-layout

Hello i would like to use angular-flax on my app and when run a commend

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout
```

its install correct but when i start server ng serve i found this error i am use angular 7

> ```
> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/class/class.d.ts(9,19): error TS2305: Module '"D:/TFS/Ta3alomLive/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgClassImpl'.
> node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/class/class.d.ts(9,33): error TS2305: Module '"D:/TFS/Ta3alomLive/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgClassR2Impl'.
> node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(9,19): error TS2305: Module '"D:/TFS/Ta3alomLive/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgStyleImpl'.
> node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(9,33): error TS2305: Module '"D:/TFS/Ta3alomLive/WebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵNgStyleR2Impl'.
> node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
> node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
> ```

Comment: Try this:  npm i -s @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk

Comment: i am try this plus install flex version 7.0.0 and now work correctly thank you